# Kernel module driver interaction

Tags: c, module, kernel, device, pwm

I'm new in kernel development. I'm trying to use PWM module from Beagle bone black board from another kernel module that I'm buinding. I have read these article:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pwm.txt

But it isn't clearly to understand. I have read the pwm-tiehrpwm under kernel source /drivers/pwm/pwm-tiehrpwm.c.

But I don't know how to use it. Are there a manual or a tutorial to use it?
Could someone tell me a skeleton for this driver?

My current system is a beaglebone black board. Running a debian distribution with Kernel version:
Linux beaglebone 4.4.9-ti-r25 #1 SMP Thu May 5 23:08:13 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

PWM Modules loaded:

lsmod | grep pwm
pwm_tiecap              3652  0 
pwm_tiehrpwm            4706  0

Using the cape-universaln:

cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots  0: PF----  -1 
 1: PF----  -1 
 2: PF----  -1 
 3: PF----  -1 
 4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-universaln

Thanks

Comment: How well is your kernel module integrated with the device tree model?

Comment: I have started using pwm-tiehrpwm.c. Initially this module is working very well, so I'm introducing changes and recompile it. but I don't know how to use your functions. I couldn't find documents that explain in details its usage.